# Calling php artisan db:seed does not work without providing a class name

Tags: php, laravel

I have a seeder class in the database folder

```
class UsersTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        $user = new User();
        $user->name         = 'Name';
        $user->email        = 'email@gmail.com';
        $user->password        = bcrypt('secret');
        $user->save();

    }
}
```

When I run `php artisan db:seed` nothing happens, the seeder is only called when I run `php artisan db:seed --class=UsersTableSeeder`

This means I have to call each seeder class separately, any idea why `db:seed` doesn't work by it self?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at `database/seeds/DatabaseSeeder.php`

You will need to add the calls to your other seeders in there.

Then `db:seed` will function as expected

Example:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $this->call(UsersTableSeeder::class);
        $this->call(SecondSeedClass::class);
        $this->call(ThirdSeedClass::class);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to register the seed classes in DatabaseSeeder class in seeds folder.
All the classes in run method will be seed on php artisab db:seed command

```
class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder {

    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run() {
        $this->call(UsersTableSeeder::class);
        $this->call(AnotherSeeder::class);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add it to the `DatabaseSeeder` class:

```
public function run()
{
    $this->call(UsersTableSeeder::class);
}
```